# same alert shows up multiple 'cancel' buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I have a game which displays an alert whenever a player wins. However after restarting the game and the same alert shows up multiple 'cancel' buttons show up. just like showed in the picture. any ideas what it could be,

```
var alertX = UIAlertController(title: "Winner", message: "X Has Won", preferredStyle:.alert) 
func AlertPlayer1() {
   alertX.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"CLOSE",style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { (action) in self.alertX.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
   self.present(alertX, animated:true, completion:nil) 
}
```

[image]

I have simply then just called the function whenever somebody wins

Comment: Show your code whatever you have tried.

Comment: Hello Hashim. Please provide your code by editing your first post. Provide any additionnal information, and be precise in both title and description to make sure you get a quick answer.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your code as following to fix issue.

```
    func AlertPlayer1() {

        var alertX = UIAlertController(title: "Winner", message: "X Has Won", preferredStyle:.alert)

        alertX.addAction(UIAlertAction(title:"CLOSE",style: UIAlertAction.Style.destructive, handler: { (action) in 
            self.alertX.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.present(alertX, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
```

You are creating alert instance single time, but this method `AlertPlayer1` call multiple time from somewhere in your code which are adding multiple close button.

> **Note:** As per I already told you, you method calling multiple time. So this alert also try to present multiple time, but at a time your can present only one view controller in window/screen. So it will show you warning in console.

Comment: wow thats fixed it.. you worked it out so quick. can you explain what was wrong please

Comment: Yes, you have created single instance of `alertX` globally which are create once but use multiple time. So when your method calling same instance is used and new button is adding in that global instance `alertX `. So I have put in your method which are create new instance every time and add single button in that alert view, means prevent to re-using single global instance.

Comment: Just wondering why the Var still needs to be there as it seems I am defining them twice here